# SQL Server FOR XML: Joining XML nodes into one XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table like the following:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (Ordinal INT, MyXML XML)
INSERT INTO @myTable (Ordinal, MyXML) VALUES (1, '<Item AnyAttribute="anyValue">1</Item>')
INSERT INTO @myTable (Ordinal, MyXML) VALUES (1, '<Item AnyAttribute="anyValue">2</Item>')
```

When I join the XML fragments into one big XML with:

```
SELECT MyXML AS 'OmitMe' FROM @myTable FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Items'), TYPE
```

I get:

```
 <Items>
  <OmitMe>
    <Item AnyAttribute="anyValue">1</Item>
  </OmitMe>
  <OmitMe>
    <Item AnyAttribute="anyValue">2</Item>
  </OmitMe>
</Items>
```

But I would like to get:

```
<Items>
    <Item AnyAttribute="anyValue">1</Item>
    <Item AnyAttribute="anyValue">2</Item>
</Items>
```

The use variables are not an option because that would imply the necessaty of a looping mechinisme like a cursor.

Any help will be appreciated!

Martin

EDIT:

A solution provided by Ed Harper can be incorporated into the larger scheme of things:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST((SELECT MyXML AS Items FROM @myTable FOR XML PATH ('')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),N'</Items><Items>',N'') AS XML)
```

It's sub-optimal, but it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Columns with a Name Specified as a Wildcard Character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500154.aspx)

> If the column name specified is a wildcard character (*), the content
>   of that column is inserted as if there is no column name specified.

```sql
SELECT MyXML AS '*' FROM @myTable FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Items'), TYPE
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. ;)

Comment: @Martin Giessen Just for completeness: You would reach the same with `SELECT MyXML AS [node()] ...` and even with `SELECT CAST(MyXML AS XML) ...`. The second works, becaus the *calculation* leads to an unnamed column.